# Android - Can't read bold text from strings.xml

Tags: android, string, bold

This is a string in strings.xml:

```
<string name="data_dd"><b>Data: </b>/string>
```

And this the java code:

```
myTextViews[pointer].setText(getResources().getText(R.string.data_dd) + data + "\n");
```

The problem is that the string data_dd is not bold in the textview. I tried also these but none of them worked:

```
<string name="data_dd"><Data><![CDATA[ <b>Data: </b> ]]> </Data></string>

myTextViews[pointer].setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.data_dd)) + data + "\n");
```

How can i do?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change :

```
myTextViews[pointer].setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.data_dd)) + data + "\n");
```

to :

```
myTextViews[pointer].setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.data_dd) + data + "\n"));
```

or test :

```
yourtextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: Change "\n" to <br> -> It's HTML now, not Java ! ;)

Comment: Ok, i solved adding myTextViews[pointer].append("\n"); :) thx!

Answer (score 0):

> **Use below code if you want to set entire myTextViews[pointer] Bold:**

in strings.xml

```
<string name="data_dd">Data: </string>
```

And in the TextView:

```
myTextViews[pointer].setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
myTextViews[pointer].setText(getResources().getText(R.string.data_dd) + data);
```

> **if you just want the heading "Data:" to be bold and rest of the text from variable "data" to be normal, then use:**

```
myTextViews[pointer].setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Data:</b>"+ data));
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean chinese?You may try like this:

```
TextPaint tp = tv.getPaint();
tp.setFakeBoldText(true);
```